# jQuery - Syntax Error in a Conditional

Tags: jquery, syntax, conditional-statements

```
$(".editAd").change({
    if ($(this).val() == 1)
        {
            $("#submitBtn").val("Next Step");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#submitBtn").val("Submit Changes");
        }
    });
```

There is a syntax error on the second line of this code. Missing : after property ID. I swore this was the proper use of val() in a conditional, but I suppose I could be wrong...

I know this is a pretty simple fix, but I can't find any resources off of a few minutes of research, and I was hoping the users of SO could help me out. :)

Thank you!

EDIT: There's always a silly error that developers make that stumps them for a period of time... Always review the ENTIRETY of your code for errors because the developer tools may not actually pick up the proper line of the error, as in this case.

Comment: try assigning the `$(this).val()` to a variable before the if and compare that. see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to include **function(){}**

```
$(".editAd").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 1)
        {
            $("#submitBtn").val() = "Next Step";
            console.log($("#submitBtn").val());
        }
        else
        {
            (element.attr("name") == "submitBtn").val() = "Submit Changes"; // no idea  what this is but it doesn't look like it will work 
        }
    });
```

Comment: I knew something didn't look right! I can't believe I didn't see that, nice catch!

Comment: There's many other things wrong with this, but i figured you would get to those sooner or later :-P

Comment: Yeah, the else case was the first version of my code, taken from another plugin that used the same kind of syntax. It will be changed to look like the if case in the future.

Comment: Taylor, please mark as answered if this answer helped you. This would allow me to gain some points. Thanks!

Comment: Aha, my apologies. I went out to lunch. :P

Answer (score 1):

`val()` is a function execution.

to set a value do something like

`$('selector').val('set me');`

not

`$('selector').val() = 'set me';`

start there.  Other things might clear up.

Comment: I'm not attempting to set a value... I'm attempting to perform an equivalency test on the value of the selector. Hence the double equals.

Comment: then what's this `$("#submitBtn").val() = "Next Step";`

Comment: and this `(element.attr("name") == "submitBtn").val() = "Submit Changes";`

Comment: I apologize. In my version of the code these changes (which I used as outlines for the proper code, from syntax written in other plugins that were not written by me) had already been fixed, and I had not referred to the code that I posted in the question.

Comment: @TaylorPLM It would be helpful to anyone with similar problem in the future if you could edit the question with the `val` calls fixed.  That way they can quickly see that omitting `function()` is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Missing : after property ID`
This is caused by the lack of a `function ()` identifier before the conditional.  Because it was bracketed `{}` the javascript parser thought you were passing an object literal with `if` as a property identifier.  It was looking for a colon after it to identify the value of the property.

---

Not sure what you are trying to do on this line:

```
(element.attr("name") == "submitBtn").val() = "Submit Changes";
```

But it looks like you are trying to call `val` on a boolean value, which is not valid.  You are also assigning a string to the output of `val()` which won't work.

To assign a value to an element, jQuery's [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) takes one parameter:

```
element.val("Submit Changes");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems with your code. Firstly, the cause of the error you are talking about, is the missing `function` keyword. That's required as the `change` method takes a function as an argument.

Next, you're assigning a value to the `val` method, which is incorrect (`$("#submitBtn").val() = "Next Step";`). You need to pass the string in as an argument.

Third, your `else` block is very confusing. I'm not sure what you were trying to do there, but  it will evaluate to something like `true.val() = "Submit Changes";` which is completely wrong. It's another assignment to a function, and you're trying to call that function on a boolean value, not a jQuery object.

So, based on all that, this is what I *think* you were trying to do:

```
$(".editAd").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        $("#submitBtn").val("Next Step");
        console.log($("#submitBtn").val());
    }
    else {
        if($(element).attr("name") == "submitBtn") {
            $(element).val("Submit Changes");
        }
    }
});
```